# Render string templates via ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to render a piece of html, available on a dynamic route, the route is fetched via a `$http.get()` call, it returns a piece of html,

Just to give an example I try to load this html partial:

```
<h1>{{ pagetitle }}</h1>
this is a simple page example
```

I made a small fiddle, to mock the problem, but for the simplicity i left the http call out, and just added the html in a string on the scope.

The controller is:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        view: "<h1>whaaaaa</h1>"        
    }; 
}
```

The page html is this:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-include src="data.view"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it does not add the string into the html file (ng-include), but it makes a http call to a url made of that string aparently.

So Is it not possible to just enter a string into an include? if not, what is the proper way to make an http call to a dynamic url, and enter the returned url into the page.

You can play with it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yq7Ev/1/).

Comment: Check your keyboard. `Shift` key specific. There may be some misfuction around it. You start most sentences with a small letter, while you should use capital one. Someone must edit your question and answers and fix that. This is a quite boring task after all. Maybe you can purchase yourself a brand new keyboard, with fully functioning `Shift` key, as your very own Christmas gift?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add static hooks to the template cache, so let's say you have a service that gets the template:

```
myApp.service('myTemplateService', ['$http', '$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
  $http(/* ... */).then(function (result) {
    $templateCache.put('my-dynamic-template', result);
  });

  /* ... */
}]);
```

Then, you can do:

```
<div include src=" 'my-dynamic-template' "></div>
```

**NOTE** reference name must be wrapped in single quotes, this always bytes me.... **NOTE**

Do note that you'll have to have assigned it to the template cache before angular tries to resolve the url.

EDIT:

If the dynamic URL logic is simple enough, you can also use a conditional in the ng-include, e.g.

```
<div ng-include="isTrue() && 'template1.html' || 'template2.html'"
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, I pull in my partial templates via AMD, and then the controller can assemble them into the $templateCache, and use ng-include="'myTpl"

Comment: Fantastic work around. To lazy load, I simply include a `ng-if` on the include and set the variable to true after populating the template.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that with [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude); reference:

> ngInclude|src – {string} – angular expression evaluating to URL. If
>   the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in quotes, e.g.
>   src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

Use directly [ng-bind-html-unsafe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe) like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="data.view"></div>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yq7Ev/4/)**</kbd>

> Creates a binding that will innerHTML the result of evaluating the
>   expression into the current element. The innerHTML-ed content will not
>   be sanitized! You should use this directive only if ngBindHtml
>   directive is too restrictive and when you absolutely trust the source
>   of the content you are binding to.

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is deprecated. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19415394/3123195 for more details and alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

<del>You can use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`</del>

If you do not trust the html which comes from your ajax request, you can also use [`ng-bind-html`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive%3angBindHtml) which needs the [`$sanitize`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.%24sanitize) service to work ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yq7Ev/7/)).

```
<div ng-bind-html="data.view"></div>
```

To use that you need to include [an extra js file](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-sanitize.js) .

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

And of course add the app to ng-app:

```
<div ng-app="app">
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) expects a URL to an external HTML fragment, not an HTML string.

You want [`ng-bind-html-unsafe`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe):

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yq7Ev/2/).

Comment: ng-bind-html-unsafe would work but it is only usefull when printing html, not html that again needs to be compiled with ng-binds and what not inside. however, i solved it by using the templatecache example from @quinnirill as that is a very clean solution without the need to extra compile the html. still thanks for the idea