# Bind Angularjs to newly created html element dynamically

Tags: angularjs, model-binding

I have a tab page with multiple tabs that once clicked on call a service to return some data.  Some of that data returns html forms and are very random.  I want to collect those values that are entered and send the data via a service back to the server.  The problem I have is that I can't get the data from the input elements in the html I'm creating dynamically.

I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PS6tN1KLr1Anv4SN54HY?p=preview) to show what the issue is.  Note that the html value can change at any time so hard-coding the html won't work.  Here the code from the plunker, but please look at the plunker for the best view of whats going on.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $compile) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.html = "";

    $scope.htmlElement = function(){
        var html = "<input type='text' ng-model='html'></input>";
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    }

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <div ng-bind-html="htmlElement()"></div>

    {{html}}

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you making DOM modifications within the controller rather than a directive?

Comment: This is only for example.  The actual html is coming from the server via a service.  No DOM manipulation in the controller.  I have been wondering if I could use a directive and $compile to get this to compile the html and bind the html to the model at that point.

Comment: Exactly you can use `$compile(element.contents())(scope)`, before that you can add string to the `element.html()` method and setup a `$watch` on the `ngModel` i dont know if thats what you are going for...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One solution would be to use ngInclude with $templateCache, as demonstrated in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xvqiWGtDD5veFVOjFnn5?p=preview).

There are a couple things to note.

The first is that you can fetch your template using a service and add it to the $templateCache, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149450/1376146) (example copied):

```
myApp.service('myTemplateService', ['$http', '$templateCache', function ($http, $templateCache) {
  $http(/* ... */).then(function (result) {
    $templateCache.put('my-dynamic-template', result);
  });
}]);
```

Then you can include it in your template as follows:

```
<div ng-include="'my-dynamic-template'"></div>
```

ngInclude will allow databinding on the html string, so you don't need ngBindHtml.

The second is that, as ngInclude creates a new scope, accessing the `html` property outside of the newly created scope won't work properly unless you access it via an object on the parent scope (e.g. `ng-model="data.html"` instead of `ng-model="html"`. Notice that the `$scope.data = {}` in the parent scope is what makes the html accessible outside of the ngInclude scope in this case.

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/1376146) for more on why you should always use a dot in your ngModels.)

---

**Edit**

As you pointed out, the ngInclude option is much less useful when using a service to return the HTML.

Here's the edited [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lyrlYA94n019C2GHTAIa?p=preview) with a directive-based solution that uses $compile, as in David's comment above.

The relevant addition:

```
app.directive('customHtml', function($compile, $http){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $http.get('template.html').then(function (result) {
        element.replaceWith($compile(result.data)(scope));
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I think this is getting closer, but doesn't really do it because the template still needs to be applied when the app if first run and can't be set at a later time like when the service call has completed.  I edited your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Np5YDftGpNpVXeFkJxNY?p=preview) to show you that the service call won't work.

Comment: Indeed :) Updated above.

Comment: @Sarah - thanks so much. I was looking for something just like this and your Plunker example is fantastic.  I forked your plunker and added a  way to append multiple template files which will append to the element.  You can see it at: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ch5uykLwlF8Td2zQEoH9?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

Based on Sarah's answer, i created a structure to put the directive

```
.directive('dynamic', function(AmazonService, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      AmazonService.getHTML()
     .then(function(result){
       element.replaceWith($compile(result.data)(scope));
     })
     .catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
     });
   }
 };
});
```

And in the html:

```
<dynamic></dynamic>
```

Thanks Sarah, helped a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a dynamic table with some ng-repeat's, then when I tried to fill one column with javascript callback function, it give me just in html text like

```
<td class="tableList_"+myValue> "span class=someclass> some_text /span>" </td>
<td class="tableList_"+myValue> "span class=someclass> some_text /span>" </td>
<td class="tableList_"+myValue> "span class=someclass> some_text /span>" </td>
```

So I resolved my problem with jquery:

```
$(".tableListFilas td").each(function() {
    var td_class = $(this).attr("class");

    if(td_class == 'tableList_'+titulo)
    {
         var toExtraHtml = $(this).text();
         $(this).html(toExtraHtml);
    }
});
```

then the final output was good:

```
<td class="tableList_COLORS"> <span class=someclass>some_text</span> </td>
<td class="tableList_COLORS"> <span class=someclass>some_text</span> </td>
<td class="tableList_COLORS"> <span class=someclass>some_text</span> </td>
```