# How to add DOM Elements (Angular directives) via jQuery's .append()?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Is there any way to add an element that is an Angular directive with jQuery methods like `append()` and have Angular do its compilation/linking to make it work as though you'd included the directive in the first place?

Example:

```
app.directive('myAngularDirective', [function () {
    ...
    // Lots of stuff in here; works when used normally but not when added via jQuery
});

$("body").append("<my-angular-directive />");
```

It currently just appends an empty DOM element called "my-angular-directive," but Angular doesn't kick in and do its magic.

Comment: My suspicion is that you'll need to tell Angular that the new element now exists, as it probably didnt exist on doc Ready if youre adding it dynamically

Comment: You really want to avoid doing any jquery if you can, but I ran into a similar problem not too long ago, here was [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867554/bind-angularjs-to-newly-created-html-element-dynamically) and the correct answer that should be able to help you out. The short answer is using $compile.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The right way to go is to use: [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) and in case your directive returns: `directive definition object` (which is btw. the recommended way to go) you can then call `link` function on it (to inject `scope`, for example).

```
$('body').append($compile("<my-angular-directive />")(scope));
scope.$apply();
```

Comment: your code is not complete. can u please post a jsfiddle version your code.

Comment: What if you're already inside a `$digest` cycle? Perhaps use `$timeout` instead.

Answer (score 17):

A complete example, from [the Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector):

```js
// Angular boilerplate
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.content = {
    label: "hello, world!",
  };
});

// Wrap the example in a timeout so it doesn't get executed when Angular
// is first started.
setTimeout(function() {
  // The new element to be added
  var $div = $("<div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>new: {{content.label}}</div>");
  
  // The parent of the new element
  var $target = $("[ng-app]");

  angular.element($target).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var $scope = angular.element($target).scope();
    $target.append($compile($div)($scope));
    // Finally, refresh the watch expressions in the new element
    $scope.$apply();
  });
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">old: {{content.label}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP was asking for directive.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should avoid doing that.

However, if you *really, really, really* need to, then you can inject and use the [`$compile` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) followed by an `element.append`.

If your *directive* doesn't need access to a specific scope, then you can even assign the `$compile` and `$rootScope` service to `window` in the `run` function of your application's module and then use them from outside the angular context by creating a new `scope` (`$rootScope.new()`) and wrap the appending of element by using `$rootScope.apply()`.

Comment: Why should appending elements dinamically be avoided? Is there an alternative?

Comment: I guess you would have that directive in a view and use something like ui.router to put the view in a ui-view

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't provide a complete example, here's one:

https://codepen.io/rhinojosahdz/pen/ZpGLZG

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl1 as ctrl1">
</body>
<script>
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){
    var vm = this;
    vm.x = 123;
    $('body').append($compile("<hola x='ctrl1.x' />")($scope));
}])
.directive('hola', function(){
    return {
        template: '<div ng-click="vm.alertXFromGivenScope()">click me!</div>'
        ,scope: {
            x : '='
        }
        ,controller: function(){
            var vm = this;
            vm.alertXFromGivenScope = function(){
                alert(vm.x);                
            };
        }
        ,controllerAs: 'vm'
        ,bindToController: true
    }
})
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.element($("#appendToDiv")).append($compile("<my-angular-directive />")($scope));
```