# Ng repeat not working inside li for pop up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a pop up using Dialog servce.

I am planning to show some message to user like this

```
    txt = '<ul> 
        <li data-ng-repeat = "eachValue in dummnyList" > 
           {{eachValue | applyFilter}}
        </li></ul>' ;
```

It is processing successfully but it considering {{eachValue | applyFilter}} as text.

- {{eachValue | applyFilter}}

Am I missing any thing.

The complete code for pop up is

```
var txt = '<ul> 
            <li data-ng-repeat = "eachValue in dummnyList" > 
               {{eachValue | applyFilter}}
            </li></ul>' ;    
var proceedButton = {label:'Ok', result: 'ok', cssClass: 'btn blue-button', returnFunction: proceedFunction};
        var cancelButton = {label:'Cancel', result: 'not ok', cssClass: 'btn red-button', returnFunction:cancelFunction};
        var buttons = [];
        buttons.push(proceedButton);
        buttons.push(cancelButton);

        DialogUtils.openMessageBox({
            title: 'Note',
            message: txt,
            buttons: buttons
        });
```

Comment: are you adding `txt` dynamicly to your page (for example with jQuery)?

Comment: @Daniel. Yes I am adding ti dynamically

Answer (score 1):

There's your problem. AngularJS does not know, that you added this code. You can use $compile to add code like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059469/3346612).

```
$('body').append($compile("<my-angular-directive />")(scope));
scope.$apply();
```

But you should think about getting rid of old jQuery and solving your problems completly with angular...

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to add compile like this txt = $compile(<ul> <li data-ng-repeat = "eachValue in dummnyList" > {{eachValue | applyFilter}}</li></ul>) ;

Comment: you need to add `'` quotes around your string, but indeed that should solve your problem: `txt = $compile('<ul> <li data-ng-repeat = "eachValue in dummnyList" > {{eachValue | applyFilter}}</li></ul>');`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to angular js. DO I need to Inject this in angular module. I have this function in controller not in directive.

Comment: where is your jQuery code located? Do you perform the actions within the controller? Then you simply need to $compile the html markup befor edding it to the page.

Comment: I am performing these actions in the controller. Will it be just enough to add  txt = $compile('<ul> <li data-ng-repeat = "eachValue in dummnyList" > {{eachValue | applyFilter}}</li></ul>');

Comment: you need to add both lines:
`txt = $compile('<ul> <li data-ng-repeat = "eachValue in dummnyList" > {{eachValue | applyFilter}}</li></ul>')(scope);` and `scope.$apply();`

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have edited the question. txt is html code. It would be great if you can post answer as per my code. That would really help me.

Answer (score 0):

In angularJS you should not modify the template outside of [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). You should create a directive to create your pop-up. You could workaround and keep your jQuery habits but this is not the way AngularJS is supposed to work.