# AngularJS - ng-click not working in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a `Modal` which opens up on a `button` click. In this `Modal`, a button uses `ng-click` to call a `function` from `js` file.The function doesn't get called, with no errors.

Outside the Modal the `ng-click` is working properly.

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="app" ng-controller="GridCtrl">
    ....
    <div id="partial"></div>
</div>

function openModal() {                 
            jq.get('/Data/openModal?Id=' + Id, function (data) {
                jq('#partial').html(data);
                jq('#Modal').modal('show');
            });    
        }
```

Partial Page :-

```
@model Models.Data
@{       
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">                    
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="compModalLabel">Master</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">    
                <div class="container">    
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button type="button" ng-click="getData('live')">Live Data</button>
                        </div>
.....
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('GridCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.getData= function (status){
    .....
}

}
]);
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

See here: [Add DOM Elements (that are Angular directives) via jQuery .append()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059231/add-dom-elements-that-are-angular-directives-via-jquery-append)

You need to have the newly added DOM elements compiled by Angular, with $compile(...)

(Although a more pure AngularJS codewould be better overall, you are mixing JQuery and NG.
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal)