# angularjs data binding with dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code in my application:

```
$scope.appendBets = function()
{
    $.each($scope.phaseBets, function(i, bet)
    {
        var betElement = angular.element('<div ng-model="phaseBets[i]">Bet id: {{phaseBets[i].id}}</div>');
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#betsHolder')).append(betElement);
        $compile(betElement)($scope);
    });
}
```

the `$scope.phaseBets` is loaded from `$http.get`.

Now the problem is that the `{{phaseBets[i].id}}` content not seen on the html page, I am getting this `Bet id:`.

I have seen [this OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867554/bind-angularjs-to-newly-created-html-element-dynamically) but it's not working for me, maybe because of the array.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

**Note**
The thing is that by the I'd I will create an element (different for each id) so ng-repeat not helping that mutch.

Comment: Stop using `jQuery`s `append` (or AngularJS's lite version) and start using `ng-repeat`. It does exactly the same thing with the added value that someone already thought of this issue and handled it for you. (I've been using AngularJS extensively, coming from a jQuery background, and found out in about a month that _I don't need this kind of manual DOM manipulation at all anymore_)

Comment: So use `ng-include` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) building the template URL based on each different ID. - Please trust us on this one: _stop_ trying do do this the jQuery way and approach it the AngularJS way. It will take some time and you will read/ask a lot of  questions on Stack Overflow, but it will be worth your time.

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu Paraschiv, that's why I ask. Still how I'll use the nginclude if I need to include different html for each id.

Comment: I also see that you are using `ng-model`. It only works on `input` nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it using `ng-repeat` and `ng-include`:

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 1, title: 'foo', data: {body: 'baz1'}},
    {id: 2, title: 'bar', data: {body: 'baz2'}}
];

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <div ng-include src="getTemplateById(item.id)"></div>
</div>
```

Where the templates are defined inline like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template-1.html">
    Content of template-1.html
    <div>{{item.data.body}}</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template-2.html">
    <p>Content of template-2.html</p>
</script>
```

and `getTemplateById` is:

```
$scope.getTemplateById = function(id) {
    return 'template-' + id + '.html';
};
```

[You can see it in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/S6RTm/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it from wrong side, in angularjs controllers/data drives the view, here you are creating elements (and even worse adding them to page) in loop (expensive DOM operations)
I'd replace your code with following

```
<div id="betsHolder">
  <div ng-repeat="bet in phaseBets track by bet.id">Bet id: {{bet.id}}</div>
</div>
```

as soon as you assign your array/object to $scope.phaseBets the DOM will be created

Comment: The thing is that by the I'd I will create an element (different for each id) so ng-repeat not helping that mutch.

Comment: What do you mean different for each id? different class, name or whatever?

Answer (score -1):

but using ng-repeat is better option,

```
   angular.forEach($scope.phaseBets, function(bet, i)
    {
        var betElement = angular.element('<div ng-model="bet">Bet id: {{bet.id}}</div>');
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#betsHolder')).append(betElement);
        $compile(betElement)($scope);
    });
```

Comment: no, no, no, never ever add DOM in loops, secondly the ng-repeat does exactly what vlio needs

Comment: agree ng-repeat is much better option, I'm just fix vlio20 code

Comment: The thing is that by the I'd I will create an element (different for each id) so ng-repeat not helping that mutch.

Comment: so my code should fix your problem, have you got your bet id in view ?