# Assigning models to dynamically created html elements in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to set models which are created dynamically by JQuery. I found a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867554/bind-angularjs-to-newly-created-html-element-dynamically) with `$compile`,   But in my case, I don't have access to those created elements at their creating time as those elements are created by a third party plugin (Like JQuery UI s). I have access only to their ID s.

So is there a way to set  models to such elements. (I use jquery 1.3)

Here is an sample: Assume I am using the slider of Jquery as mentioned [here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) . `#slider` is only the div in our accessible layout. Rest of elements are created by the JQuery UI.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
  </script>
</head><body> 
<div id="slider"></div> 
</body>
```

The sliding gadget is created with a span,

```
<span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 9%;"></span>
```

This span is created by jquery dynamically. In this case, I want to set a angular model to this `<span>` ?

Comment: Please provide some code. The jQuery models, the controller and the view.

Comment: @DavidBarker. Thanks for your prompt reply. I modified my question with exact sample.

Comment: Might want to simply use and angular ready slider. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/demo/demo.html Angular UI often have most UI stuff made from jQuery and others as angular module so it's all done the angular way and support ng-model by default. Also it means it's often possible to build everything without needed the full jQuery.

Comment: @gillesc. Thanks for you answer. But thing is, what if there are more plugins if already set to page ? I will have to move all plugins to angular .. :( . Isn't there any other way ?