# Pass value and unique identifier to function with ng-change with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, dynamic

It's a huge title, but it tells about everything, but let me clarify.

I have generator that produces a HTMLstring for an input field (range, checkbox, ...).
This massive string then gets placed in the HTML via `$templateCache.put('dynamicSettings, htmlString)`

Example of a possible string:

```
var htmlString = "<input type='range' min='0' max='10' value='5' ng-model='sliderBrightness' ng-change='settingsInputChanged(sliderBrightness, 'sliderBrightness')'>";
```

When I hardcode this string in my HTML file, it works perfectly.
The settingsInputChanged() function gets called and 2 parameters are passed, the value and the unique name. The function then saves the value in the localStorage with the keyvalue (2nd parameter).

But when adding the string dynamically, I get this massive error of which I presume has something to do with the fact that I'm passing a String in the ng-change.

```
rror: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [settingsInputChanged(sliderBrightness,] starting at [settingsInputChanged(sliderBrightness,].
```

Or maybe it can't handle that I have 2 '-pairs nested.

Can I change my string to not use those '-pairs to pass my string to the function in the ng-change?

Comment: notice that you close the opening single quote right after `ng-change` right after the first `sliderBrightness`, thus making the expression you pass to `ng-change` invalid.

Comment: @Mosho I know I did this, but it doesn't work as I suggested in my question. I'm looking for a way to pass a string in the ng-change directive, without using a '-pair