# Define html with ng-click in controller Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

i just working with Wikitude and Google maps in AngularJS(Ionic). I need to set ng-click event for InfoWindow in my controller. My code:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: $scope.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng
  });

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<a href="#" ng-click="launchAR(\'my_world_pls\')">CATCH!</a>'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
  });

});
```

Comment: okay. What happens when you try your code?

Comment: Nothing, marker and infowindow is rendered. But link is not active

Comment: Can you remove the `href` on the `a` tag and try?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link dynamically created HTML directly to controller. There are two options mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867554/bind-angularjs-to-newly-created-html-element-dynamically)

Other option is to use jQuery. For this you can give an `id` to the `anchor element`and find the element by ID and attach click event.

Comment: That solution with jQuery sounds good. But how to attach angular event like: $scope.launchAR = function(){};

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function() {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: $scope.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      $scope.launchAR('mana_catch_and_eat');
    });

  });
```