# How to bind array elements by id with dom class elements in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a `page_elements` array with appropriate `.grid-cell` index in string html, so that it would be displayed on the page instead within my directive. I store indexes of given cell elements and then filter them to retrieve matching page_elements objects.

However, I can't rid of the redundancy of `ng-repeat` in grid where is more then one element. A removed element is replaced with an empty object `{}`, but it should be spliced in order to keep grid elements in right places. Moved elements should be able to drop into other grid cells. If indexes would be properly assigned then directive should work with [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists), how to fix it?

How can I display `ng-repeat` with matched `page_elements` only once in given grid? e.g. now `page_elements` where `grid_id: 2` is displayed three times in `ng-repeat` in third grid. How to remove permanently page element object and keep cell elements in right places? Also Drag&Drop mechanism is broken in current solution.

Current code snippet and [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/r28zzowL/20/):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['dndLists']);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.html_string = "<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-4 grid-cell'></div><div class='col-xs-4 grid-cell'></div><div class='col-xs-4 grid-cell'></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-4 grid-cell'></div><div class='col-xs-4 grid-cell'></div><div class='col-xs-4 grid-cell'></div></div></div></div></div>";

    $scope.page_elements = [{
        "grid_id": 0,
            "position": 0,
            "snippet": "<h4>First Grid 0</h4>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 0,
            "position": 1,
            "snippet": "<h2>Second Grid 0</h2>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 1,
            "position": 0,
            "snippet": "<h2>First Grid 1</h2>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 1,
            "position": 1,
            "snippet": "<h2>Second Grid 1</h2>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 2,
            "position": 0,
            "snippet": "<h1>First Grid 2</h1>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 2,
            "position": 1,
            "snippet": "<h2>Second Grid 0</h2>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 2,
            "position": 2,
            "snippet": "<h2>Third Grid 0</h2>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 5,
            "position": 0,
            "snippet": "<h2>Before Last</h2>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }, {
        "grid_id": 5,
            "position": 1,
            "snippet": "<h2>Last</h2>",
        "template": "snippet"
    }];
    $scope.page_elements_pretty = angular.toJson($scope.page_elements, true);
    $scope.rmElement = function (i) {
        debugger
    };
})
    .directive('grid', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            html_string: '=htmlstring',
            page_elements: '=pageelements'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('html_string', function (html) {
                element.html(html);

                var grid_cell = element.find('.grid-cell');
                for (var celli = 0; celli < grid_cell.length; ++celli) {
                    var cell_eli = '';
                    for (var eli = 0; eli < scope.page_elements.length; ++eli) {
                        if (scope.page_elements[eli].grid_id === celli) {
                            cell_eli += scope.page_elements.indexOf(scope.page_elements[eli]);
                        }
                    }
                    var cell_html = '<div class="layout-grid"><div class="drop-area"><div dnd-list="page_elements">';
                    cell_html += '<div ng-repeat="item in page_elements | cell_elements:\'' + cell_eli + '\'" dnd-draggable="item" dnd-moved="page_elements[page_elements.indexOf(item)].pop()" ng-click="page_elements[page_elements.indexOf(item)] = {}" ng-include="item.template + \'.html\'" dnd-effect-allowed="move"></div>';
                    cell_html += '</div></div></div>';

                    $(grid_cell[celli]).empty().append(cell_html);
                }
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}).filter('cell_elements', function () {
    return function (page_elements, cell_eli_str) {
        var cell_elms = cell_eli_str.split('').map(Number);
        var matched = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < page_elements.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < cell_elms.length; ++j) {
                if (i === cell_elms[j]) {
                    matched.push(page_elements[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return matched;
    }
});
```

```css
.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.drop-layout .layout-grid {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.drop-layout .layout-grid [class^=col-] {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}

.drop-layout div[dnd-list], .drop-layout div[dnd-list] > div {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-layout .drop-area div[dnd-list] {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.drop-layout .drop-area div {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
}

.drop-layout .drop-area .dndDragging {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.drop-layout .drop-area .dndDraggingSource {
  display: none;
}

.drop-layout .drop-area .dndPlaceholder {
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
  min-height: 48px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/master/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.min.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl" class="drop-layout">
    <h1>Grid:</h1>
    <grid htmlstring="html_string" pageelements="page_elements"></grid>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="snippet.html">
      <div class="item">{{item.snippet}} {{item.position}}</div>
    </script>
    <h1>Compile dynamic HTML</h1><h5>How to live preview of filled by elements html?</h5>
    <textarea ng-model="html_string" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
    <p>Assign elements to .grid-cells: <pre>{{page_elements}}</pre></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please better describe what you are trying to achieve with this. Right now I can only say this is a totally wrong approach, you should never build HTML out of strings like that, especially not when AngularJS's goal is to help you do that easier using `ng-repeat` and `ng-bind`.

Comment: I have not better approach, but I am still looking for. I would like to bind together predefined on server page_elements(plugins) with also predefined on server html layout string, in the goal to make it working with [angular drag and drop lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists), finnally I want to send only `page_elements` array to server

Comment: So you need `orderBy` on an `ng-repeat`? Where you order by `position`?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I won't `orderBy` because I will use `dnd-move` callback and then reorder position manually to save in relational database.

Comment: See if you can use http://ui-grid.info/ instead of building your own directive

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149314/2020425) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416224/2020425) I think what you actually want is `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

For ng-bind-html-unsafe, you directly reference the ng-repeat variable and the result will be used for the element's .innerHTML.

I tried editing your jsfiddle, but I'm not sure I got the desired effect: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fs8poxr/)